# Unable to delete question with answers even with dialog that says it has answers

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, user-experience

Here is the bug:

> Delete this answered question?
>
> We do not recommend deleting questions **with answers** because doing so deprives future readers of this knowledge.
>
> Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?

I click OK. Then it says:

> Sorry, this question **has answers** and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead.

Huh?!? Bug?!?

Comment: Does one of the answers have at least one upvote? If so, that's a feature.

Comment: @gunr2171 Then delete should throw only the later error or not display delete.

Comment: If the delete link is removed, people are going to ask where it went. It's the same as voting on your own post. The up/down buttons are still there, and only after you _try_ to vote does it say that you can't. I see no reason to change this.

Comment: @gunr2171 then display the later prompt of "Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead."

Comment: This is not a bug.  You are not allowed to delete a question that has multiple answers.  You are allowed to delete a question with a *single* answer, if it doesn't have a positive score.

Comment: @Servy then just display the later prompt of "Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead."

Comment: Well they obviously want you to read both messages.

Comment: @Pinch It does.  If you're simply asking for the first warning to be omitted, I don't see a compelling reason to do so.  What benefit is there in that?

Comment: @gunr2171 I am saying that only one message should show "Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead."

Comment: @Servy, the benefit is not being annoyed. Having a click-through verification just to get to a dead end is inefficient. Just tell me I can't do it up front. (Real comment: forget the check and just allow the deletion anyway. It's not like this site is starved for content.)

Comment: @user414076, a great clarification. Thanks.

Comment: I think that it would be a UX bug if you show a confirmation screen for a post that can't be deleted in the first place

Comment: Why not display a disabled delete option, and when users hover over delete a tooltip displays the reason it's disabled?

Comment: MSO already has this as a [meta-tag:feature-request]: [If we can't delete a question, don't show us a warning about deleting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232350/if-we-cant-delete-a-question-dont-show-us-a-warning-about-deleting-it)

Comment: @Deduplicator I asked it here first.

Comment: @Pinch: Ah, yes, it's the other way around.