# Thoughts about the "disciplined" badge and question ban

Tags: discussion, badges, post-ban

Is it possible that the [disciplined badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined) can have a potential negative and conflicting outcomes?

What will happen in the following scenario:

- User decide to delete some prehistoric questions, even [answered questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313854/statistics-on-answered-questions-deleted-by-their-author) that are not up with the current standard of questions on SO.

Can the user then be awarded with the new shiny *disciplined badge*, while also get themselves a Question ban at the same time?

I'm editing the question because I forgot to ask if the system also trigger the message [described here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256556/unable-to-delete-question-with-answers-even-with-dialog-that-says-it-has-answers) as some type of a false alarm? I'm just not completely sure if those conflict with each other or not - The tag encourage to delete the questions, white the message warns about the ban, and I'd be happy if I could get a clarification about that too.

If this scenario is possible - I think some clarification may be required about getting the *disciplined badge* the right way, without getting a question ban as-well.

Comment: FWIW shog has stated that the deletion status play a very minor role in the ban calculation.

Comment: The post must have a score of 3 or more before the badge is awarded.  That never increases the odds for a ban.

Comment: Generally speaking, you can't delete your own questions which have an answer anyhow, so this would primarily focus on answers.  Chances are *very good* that you have an answer on a question with a score of 3 or higher.

Comment: But will the user still get the warning about the deletion as [described here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256556/unable-to-delete-question-with-answers-even-with-dialog-that-says-it-has-answers)? Do you show this message always or is it targeted for specific cases where a question ban is in fact a possible as a result from the deleting a specific question? (And i'm talking about question that meets the the requirements of the badge as-well)

Comment: to [quote Shog9](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/145999): *"Deleted posts are mostly irrelevant to the question ban. If someone tells you otherwise, tell them they're wrong; if you see a meta post that says otherwise, edit it. [...] The one exception involves deleting a question right after someone posts an answer to it. "* So this should not be a concern for the "disciplined" badge.

Comment: @HugoRune I'm not sure about two things in your reference. The use of the word `mostly` - This mean that there are some rare cases where it is relevant to the question ban. Second - The use of the word `irrelevant`, who decide if a question is relevant, is it some type of algorithm or an actual human moderator.  I doubt if all those decisions are made manually, and I don't know if an algorithm would be smart enough to detect this conflict

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, I forgot to mention you in my previous comment asking about the warning before deleting a post

Comment: The process is entirely automated, a human moderator is not involved. The exact algorithm is not public. But the wording here seems straightforward to me: "irrelevant" meaning "does not change the result of the algorithm; "mostly irrelevant"  meaning "always irrelevant, with the one exception mentioned in the next paragraph" (and the next paragraph confirms that this is the only exception)

Comment: Note that this does not say that deleted questions are ignored for the question ban, just that they are counted in the same way as if they were not deleted. So it not the deleted question which is irrelevant; irrelevant is merely whether it is deleted or not.

Comment: @HugoRune Thanks for clarifying this. I'll also wait for Hans to answer my previous question in the comments above about the warning before the deletion, I would like to know from an internal source on SO if this message is triggered always or for specific cases. It will help me to understand if it's just a false warning in this case (Which in this case is might be misleading)

Comment: Side note: since badges are permanent I believe you can delete and restore the post later if you so concerned about question ban (I would not recommend that way of cheating to get the badge, just highlighting the  possibility)

Comment: I have been looking and can't seem to find.. How can I get a Disciplined badge if I can't even delete my own posts (since all my questions with a 3+ upvote will have answers, making me unable to delete them)??

Comment: @SurestTexas "Post" can also include answers, so if you delete an answer with +3 votes you should get the badge. If you want to delete a questions like the ones you describe, you'll have to [contact](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) SO directly and ask the get the questions deleted (But I don't think you'll get the badge by doing so)

Comment: OK.. it is kind of misleading how the text for the badge reads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can earning the Disciplined badge get you question-banned?

**No.**

Even if you earn the badge by deleting an answered question that tons of other folks have invested time into... You're still deleting *one* question that was otherwise *well-received*. Question bans are intended to address folks with a *history* of *poorly-received* questions.

Now, if you go and delete *all* of your questions, and you have lots of them, you might conceivably earn the badge *and* a ban. Or just get suspended because the system and/or a moderator decides your account has been hacked. But that's not what you're asking about anyway.

Comment: So if i were hacked and had got all my questions deleted , is there anyway  SO can possibly get back all my previous questions?

Comment: Yes. All deletions are "soft" - they can be undeleted.

Comment: What about the ban then?

Comment: Then it would go away.